Simple yet incredibly frustrating lua pattern
I'm working with Luasnip, and for my latex setup I have some snippets that would make sense to run only if the previous character is a digit, a letter, or a curly brace. The digit and numbers work flawlessly, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to include this closing curly brace. I've escaped it every way I can think of with no success. Here is the pattern I'm working with currently, but if anyone can explain how to include the closing curly brace in that set that would be phenomenal.
"([%a%d}])_" -- _ should be the trigger character for a subscript in this case.


The pattern itself should be valid and correct (print(('}_'):match('([%a%d}])_')) -- '}'). How are you using it?

In Luasnip. For some reason the %a and %d work fine, but for the life of me I can't get this to work. This is the whole snippet:
s( { trig = "([%a%d%}])_", regTrig = true, snippetType = "autosnippet", name = "autosnippet subscript", dscr = "autosnippet subscript", }, fmta([[<>_{<>}]], { f(function(_, snip) return snip.captures[1] end), i(1) }), utils.mathOnly),
Sorry. The block codeblock in a comment looked hideous. This is actually better.
